# use resource from another server

Tags: php, pdo, instance

I would like to know if this would be possible to use a Resource instance from another server.

For example, I would like to be able to retrieve data from a database using PDO on server A, and using the returned resource in server B (but not with an API, I'd like to use the resource as if I just made the PDO request from server B.

Is that possible ? Is it the purpose of PHP Streams ?

Thank you

Comment: You can connect to any mySQL server. Does not have to be on the same machine as PHP.

Comment: Please consider here that MySQL server A is not accessible from external client.

Comment: There is information inside the PDO class which can only be used on the server it's connecting from.  You would have to make a new connection from the second server - which sounds like you are not allowed to.

Comment: Nope, obviously it's not possible by means of PHP. But quite trivial by using SSH tunnels